# Ubuntu won't boot at start up I have to go into BIOS

Tags: boot, boot-repair

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10. I have it installed on a hard drive, and have another SSD (which is empty). When I turn on my PC it boots up to a black screen with a flickering underscore in the top right corner. So I have to go into the boot option menu and pick my hard drive to boot into Ubuntu. I went into BIOS so as to permanently boot from my hard drive but only my SSD and DVD drive are showing in the BIOS boot options. So it's booting from SSD which is empty. I had previously tried to install Ubuntu on it before, but was frustrated and instead installed it on my hard drive. I have a Gigabyte H97-HD3 motherboard.

Comment: If the BIOS won't detect the HDD, how are you booting at all?

Answer (score 0):

I think there will not be any bootloader installed in your hdd. Usually bootloader will be installed on the mbr partition of the disk. If you want to boot from hdd ,use some tool to make your operating system bootable on hdd.In ubuntu you can use command line tool dd or graphical tool startup disk creator for making it. Hope it helps..

Comment: Could you go into detail on how I could do that? Thanks.

Comment: You may [edit] this answer rather than giving another

Answer (score 0):

[Start up disk creator -- ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IooVB.png)

Source disk image -- choose the iso file you have to make bootable.
Disk to use       -- choose your hdd.

Then click make startup disk.

Answer (score 0):

## Boot-Repair utility

Try Linux Boot-Repair utility which comes with many distributions.  It can fix most boot problems.

Comment: A totally useless answer.  At best it is a comment. An answer by definition is a COMPLETE solution to a problem. Not a try this.